# I get an error when I build my ExtWebComponents chart web component, no matching files, how do I resolve it?

Tags: extjs, extwebcomponents

When I build my ExtWebComponents application, I get this error.

**Error**

ℹ ｢ext｣: C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Ext.chart.theme.Midnight) -- /build/ext/manifest.js:0:13

**Other Forms of the Error**

- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/branflake2267/git/sandbox-ewc/dash-metrics/dash-metrics-client/build/widget/cartesian.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

**My Config**

```
Ext.require([
  'Ext.chart.theme.Midnight',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Green',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Muted',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Purple',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Sky',
  'Ext.chart.series.Area',
  'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
  'Ext.chart.axis.Category'
]);
```

**Source**

- https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/07fbe9a79c90e2c85bb34821298d53a8

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman You should check out the help section on "Answering Your Own Questions": https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Posting and answering your own question is a specific use case that Stack Overflow was designed around as a way to share information.

Comment: This I would say isn't a flaw, but a side affect for an incorrect configuration. And my point here is to share how to fix the configuration, which falls under StackOverflows mission in helping devs find information. My goal is to help others find solutions to issues quickly on StackOverflow. One thing to note StackOverflow has a mechanism to answer my own questions but also foster better responses than my own. So I'm excited to hear if others have better answers than my own.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth , If one post 3 questions and immediately answers them being the Product Manager of mentioned tooling; I prefer to go by  https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion over the self answer guidelines.

Comment: If you want to post an answer you are more than welcome to, and the original question is relevant to Stack Overflow. The self promotion rule would be if someone posted a general question and then someone like Brandon posted an answer about his product. The question is well written and on topic, as is the answer.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth precisely: "someone like Brandon posted an answer about his product". 4 times.

Comment: I feel like I followed the guidelines closely, don't show, tell the story, aiming not to be a snake oil salesman. I spent more time on showing how to solve 4 particular angles related to the product. We get a lot of questions in this department, so I spent some extra time trying to help in this department. I don't see anybody else posting questions, so I started posting. I figure things like this will help end users putting together apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this error, the `charts` package has to be added to the ExtWebpackPlugin.

```
new ExtWebpackPlugin({
  framework: 'web-components',
  toolkit: 'modern',
  theme: 'theme-material',
  emit: emit,
  script: './extract-code.js',
  port: 8080,
  packages: [
      'renderercell',
      'font-ext',
      'ux',
      'd3',
      'pivot-d3',
      'font-awesome',
      'exporter',
      'pivot',
      'calendar',
      'charts', // <<<<<------
      'treegrid',
      'froala-editor'
  ],
  profile: profile,
  environment: environment,
  treeshake: treeshake,
  browser: browser,
  watch: watch,
  verbose: verbose,
  inject: 'yes',
  intellishake: 'no'
})
```

Example: https://github.com/sencha/ext-web-components/blob/ext-web-components-7.1.x/packages/ext-web-components-kitchensink/webpack.config.js#L45